# Sharepoint row hyperlink

Tags: xslt, sharepoint

I'm new to this Sharepoint design.

I have a created a new list page and I want one entry of each row to hyperlink to a different page.

Sl      Title         Topic       Subject

1      **ABC**        TABC        SABC

2      **DEF**        TDEF        TSABC

So, basically what i want is when I click on ABC under title column it should take me to a page & when I click on DEF they would take me to a different page which I have added by Clicking on Hyperlink.

The current scenario is whenever I add a Hyperlink all the Column entries for Title automatically take the same link.

I tried to change this bit and individually add for each entry to no avail.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" /><a href="../xxx/"></a></xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
```

The xxx is the link to the one of the List Pages I created.

Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks,
Sandip

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Currently your xslt assigns the same path to all hyperlinks.

What you need to do is enter a path for each item. Store it in a dedicated column, for example called PageLink. Then you can use that column within your xslt:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />
  <a href="{$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@PageLink}"></a>
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: I tried. But, it's throwing up a lot of errors.

Is there a different way to do what I am trying to achieve. I mean by using a template or something else instead of a Custom List.

Comment: By default the title will always link to the display form. Unless you use a Links list. Note that I corrected the code, hopefully it'll work better.